# Express fetching data promise is pending

Tags: javascript, express, server, fetch

I've written 2 snippets of code - client and server. When the client clicks the button he sends information to the server, which uses the Riot API to retrieve summoner info. Now I want to send it back to the client but once I fetch it my promise response is pending and result is undefined. Promises are a new thing for me. Here's the code,
Client:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function sendInfo(){
                let name = document.getElementById("checker").value;
                let data = {name};
                fetch("/api", {
                     method: "POST",
                     headers: {
                         "Content-type": "application/json"
                    },
                     body: JSON.stringify(data)
                 });

                 //let data = document.getElementById("levelID");
                 fetch("/level", {
                    headers : { 
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                    }
                 })
                    .then(function(res){
                        console.log(res.json());
                    })
                    .then(function(data){
                        console.log(data);
                    })
                    .catch(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                    });
                 

            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="text" name="checkPlayer" id="checker"><br>
        <button onclick="sendInfo()">Search summoner!</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Server:

```
const PORT = 3000;

const axios = require("axios");
const express = require("express");
const path = require('path');
const key = "RGAPI-50e38ac8-4629-4abc-aef9-68e4259448bd";
const parser = require("body-parser");

var jsonParser = parser.json();

//let puuid, summonerID, level;
let summoner;

const app = express();

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("listening at 3000");
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/main.html'));
    //searchBySummonerName("RnkzOnFire");
});

app.post("/api", jsonParser, (req, res) => {
    searchBySummonerName(req.body.name);
});

app.get("/level", (req, res) => {
    res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(summoner));
});

function searchBySummonerName(name){
    const searchURL = "https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/" + name + "?" + "api_key=" + key;
    axios.get(searchURL).then((res) => {
        summoner = res.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: A promise will be pending until you use `await` or `.then()` on it to wait for it to finish and give you a value.

Comment: So I would need to add a 3rd .then()?

Comment: Also, you don't `res.send()` or `res.write()` anything in your `app.post("/api", jsonParser, (req, res) => {` handler.

Comment: You have multiple asynchronous programming errors in your code.  1) In the client, you send the `/api` request, but you don't wait for it to complete before sending the `/level` request.  2) There is no error handling on the `/api` request.  3) On the server in the `/api` request handler, you aren't sending any response back to the caller so the caller will never think it completes (and eventually will timeout).  4) In `searchBySummonerName()`, you should never stuff an asynchronous value like this into a higher scoped variable.  98% of the time, this is an anti-pattern.

Comment: Instead, return the promise you got from `axios.get()` from your function and have the caller use `.then()` or `await` on the returned value to get the value.  This way the caller knows when the function completed and can act accordingly and can also catch/handle errors.

Comment: 5) The return value from a `.then()` handler becomes the resolved value for the next step in the promise chain.   So, where you have `.then(...).then(...).catch(...)`, when you have no return value from the first `.then()` handler, then the resolved value for the next `.then()` handler will be `undefined` since there was no return value from the previous `.then()`.

Comment: How would 1 3 and 4 looks like code